# How can I find all wiki pages that link to a specific wiki page?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I'm not entirely sure if this is the right place to ask, but I'll give it a try. If not, please point me to the right Stack Exchange site.

I have found a page in a wiki (based on the MediaWiki software) with a Google search. The URL is http://somesite.com/wiki/index.php?title=sometitle. How can I find out which other sites in this wiki link to this specific URL or site?

Comment: Click on "What links here"...

Comment: Wow.. that was.. easy. Tanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy: click on "What links here" in the sidebar.

Documentation: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:What_links_here